# Flyout Images Position with CSS3 Class and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a stack image that fly's out (SIMILAR TO http://goo.gl/OJlfmG) on different position. Once it's on an area, it animates to its position via:

```
$parent.find('img#photo2').animate({left: "200px", top: "200px"});
```

I can also get it to animate with:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pop2{
    0% {
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 200px);
    }
}
```

I want to use a Class version of this CSS animation effect so that I can use addClass and RemoveClass jQuery attribute perfectly.

```
$parent.find('img#photo2').addClass('pop2');
```

Is there a way to make CSS3 class animate from the top left of the document, to work with JQUERY? I've tried changing the CSS and a few other settings with no luck.

Here is my Jquery fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5DFJq/1/

If you could show me a better way and the solution in JS Fiddle that would be great thanks!

Comment: SEE REF IMAGE: http://prntscr.com/34jm1d

Comment: Are you by any chance still looking for an answer to this one? If yes, please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/5DFJq/3/).